# What type of performance should I expect out of web services?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, soap

What type of performance should I expect out of web services? I have an application that is averaging between 2 an 7 call per second on a simple GetServerTime() method. This method only returns a date from the server. I am using WCF and making the call over SSL.  I know this question is really relative but I am just looking for some ballpark figures.

Comment: Are you using IIS or the dev web server?  How are you testing the number of calls you can make?  One client or many?

Comment: Why are you using WCF?  It sounds like you can accomplsih the same thing using ASMX web service without all the WCF binding configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very much "it depends".

There are some real-world test results here that are based on a given CPU / Memory etc scenario:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978411.aspx

It shows Binary TCP services to be more performant for Request Per Second but HTTP web services do well for Response Time vs User Load... I'll let you read and digest the full details.